# When is auxiliary "do" used in positive declarative sentences?

Tags: do-support

Examples:

- "I did go home" instead of "I went home".
- "We did make some tea" instead of "We made some tea".
- "I do listen to future garage music" instead of "I listen to future garage music".

Is it correct?

Answer (score 12):

They are correct. They are used as emphasis, though; you should not use "I did go home." every time you mean "I went home."

For example, suppose you talk to a friend of yours, and the dialog is the following one.

> **Friend**: Where did you go after school?
>   **You**: I went home.
>   **Friend**: Strange, Charlie told me you were going to the library.
>   **You**: I changed my mind. Shirley told me she was going to the library too and I didn't want to meet her there.
>   **Friend**: Michael saw you close to the library.
>   **You**: Going home, I turn right before reaching the library.
>   **Friend**: I don't believe you. Somebody took my book when I was at the library and I believe it was you.
>   **You**: Look, I did go home.

*I did go home* has the same meaning of *I went home*. It is used to put emphasis on the verb, such as to mean *I really went home*.

Answer (score 5):

The sentences that you have posted are correct, but only in certain situations.
These sentences add **emphasis** to your statement.

All of these sentences:

> I did go home
>   We did make some tea
>   I do listen ***to*** future garage music (little mistake here)

are usually used when giving a *positive* answer to a *negative* question.

For eg.

> Do you not play football?
>   ---> I **do** play football.

Comment: Both your answer and @kiamlaluno's make sense to me, but each seems to paint an incomplete picture.  To combine them, perhaps you could say the sentences with "do" or "did" are *contrary to the listener's expectation or belief*.

Answer (score 4):

*Do* is used in this way only for emphasis, and when it occurs in speech it is stressed. It can also occur at the beginning of an imperative clause: **’Do** go home now’, and can sometimes replace an entire imperative clause: ‘Do you think I should go home now?’ ‘Yes, **do**.’

(*Listen* needs to be followed by *to*, so it's *I listen **to** garage music.*)

Comment: Hey! I pointed it out too! That's not fair.